# Is there a way to link the source data for a chart to the values selected from a dropdown box?

Tags: excel, vba, visualization

[image: Graph and date selectors]
So I've created a graph to appear on this separate sheet titled "Report", and above it you can see that there are two dropdown boxes in which a user can select a specific date range. I would essentially like to link this user-specified date range to the range displayed on the graph. I'm having trouble figuring out how to link the source data for the chart to the date selectors.

[image: SourceData for Graph]
The data for the chart is sourced from this separate sheet titled "Database", in which the data is chronologically ordered with corresponding Feed values. The goal is to match the dates selected by the user in the "Report" section to the dates in this "Database" sheet, and after finding the corresponding initial and start date, apply that same logic to the feed data to strictly display the feed data within that date range.

[image: Macro for Chart]

I am currently sourcing the chart data using this Macro, the xData and yData are linked to lists titled "Dates" and "FeedTonnage", which are basically tables I made out of the columns in the database. I'm not sure if the tables are even needed, but the database will continue to be updated overtime as more data will be coming in so I thought a table would've been useful for this.

So I've been trying to write a sub that sifts through the Date column to look for a date that matches the dates selected in the "Report" sheet. I'm doing this because I intend on using the cell address to get the corresponding data from the Feed column by replacing the column portion of the cell address with that of the Feed, and yeah, I'm kinda lost at this point so I could really use some input.

Comment: Please post your code as text

Comment: Instead of changing the data range of the chart, you could hide the rows outside the selected dates

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I could hide them for a specific range, but then I'd need to hide the ones outside of the desired range everytime. I'd like to automate that part if possible

Comment: Hiding the rows can be done with VBA

Comment: Could you please show me how that could be done in this situation? I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure how to implement it, or a similar example if you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the data range of the chart, you can hide the rows of data outside the selected dates:

```
Worksheets("Database").Rows("3:100").Hidden = False
For i = 3 To 100
    If Worksheets("Database").Range("A" & i).Value < Worksheets("Report").Range("B1").Value Or Worksheets("Database").Range("A" & i).Value > Worksheets("Report").Range("C1").Value Then
        Worksheets("Database").Rows(i).Hidden = True
    End If

Next i
```

The code above assumes the dates are in the range `A3:A100`, the start date is in `B1` and the end date is in `C1`. Adjust the ranges as needed

Comment: Perfect I see what you're doing and I really like the concept. Given the list of dates and the date selectors are on different sheets, could you show me how to write the macro assuming the list of dates were on the sheet titled "Database" and the date selectors are in a sheet titled "Report".

Comment: You need to qualify which worksheet each range is on, see the edit to my answer

Comment: You're literally a god, thank you so much, got what I needed.

Comment: Instead of deifying me, it would be better to mark the answer as correct

Comment: this my first ever stack post mb homie